# IOS emulator working app is not installed on it

Tags: xcode, cordova

I have started the IOS emulator through apache cordova CLI and it works, says the build is successful. I can interact with the emulator however my app is not installed on it?

Is there a command that im missing to install my app on this emulated device?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To build

```
 cordova build ios
```

To run in emulator

```
cordova emulate ios
```

To run in device

```
cordova run ios
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be a bug in Cordova CMD. Try the following commands from your project root directory:

1) `cordova build --emulator`

2) `ios-sim launch platforms/ios/build/emulator/<your_app_name>.app --devicetypeid "com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-5s, 8.1"`

If you don't have ios-sim install it: `npm install -g ios-sim`